# Chromium fail to save http authentication credentials

Tags: google-chrome, debian, chromium

My version of chromium (6.0.472 from Debian testing distro) doesn't seem to save or even ask to save the HTTP auth user name and password. Nothing useful found on the net except to patch the sources and rebuild it.

I am talking about the HTTP authentication protocol (Basic), not the authentication on application level (html form).

I have tried to directly insert a row in the `Login Data.logins` sqlite3 table to no avail:

```
sqlite> insert into logins (origin_url, action_url, username_element, username_value, password_element,
> password_value, signon_realm,ssl_valid,preferred,date_created,blacklisted_by_user,scheme)
> VALUES ("http://website.com/","http://website.com/","username","******","password","*****","http://website.com",O,1,1304597401,0,0);
```

I know that it has been an issue for some versions but I am hoping there can be a work around by inserting the right values in the sqlite table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really using Chromium 6, then you should definitely update to at least Chromium 15 or so (and the stable version seems to be still the one you mentioned, according to http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=chromium).